# Getting WMS tiles as pyramid in bbox

Tags: geoserver, wms, tiles, tilecache

I wan to get 256px tiles of a geoserver wms service. I specified a bounded box like this:

```
-87.746754646322, 41.894876003264 -87.710705757162, 41.869813442229
```

But tiles are pyramid format. Wms service is 9 level and request parameter does not contain zoom level parameter.

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/GIS/wms?LAYERS=GIS:ways&STYLES=&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&SRS=EPSG%3A36100&BBOX=-87.746754646322,41.894876003264-87.710705757162,41.869813442229&WIDTH=259&HEIGHT=256
```

This request returns all ways that bbox contains.

Bu I want to get all tiles with programatically like pyramid in bbox like this:

```
tile1.png
tile1.png tile2.png
tile1.png tile2.png tile3.png
tile1.png tile2.png tile3.png tile4.png
```

Comment: you will need a tile aware client to do this - what are you using or are you writing you r own in which case which language are you using?

Comment: @iant, don't underestimate GeoServer. This may not be a perfect hit but rather close still http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/mbtiles/output.html. Or this one http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/geopkg/output.html#geopackage-wms-output-format.

Comment: @user30184 both of those options assume the OP has access to the Server as an admin

Comment: Sure, @iant, I just meant to give an example that the task could be handled also on the server side. If I had to get that result as soon as possible I believe I would install MapProxy with a file cache http://mapproxy.org/docs/1.8.0/caches.html and web mercator grid and seed the desired BBOX with it.

Comment: The unsupported GeoTools tilelayer might also be a good starting point